# gameDisplay.fill(white) NameError: name 'white' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "D:\ninja_car.py", line 32, in 
>        gameDisplay.fill(white)
>   NameError: name 'white' is not defined

My code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Ninja Game')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load('car.png')

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y))

x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)

crashed = False

while not crashed:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

    gameDisplay.fill(white)    # here
    car(x,y)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

What is the problem here? I'm using Python 3.4. Trying to set the background to white but it gives that error.

Comment: Where did you defined the white variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any instance of the variable white so it will give you an error. add this code:
`white = (255, 255, 255)` to where you defined the variables.

Here is the full code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

white = (255, 255, 255) # Here is the new code!

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Ninja Game')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load('car.png')

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y))


x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)


crashed = False

while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

     gameDisplay.fill(white)
     car(x,y)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```